# How to do routing on child element of tree table?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

On click of the last element of tree table, I want to route it to another screen (url) and show a table.

For example:

I want to select the last node of the parent node of every element in the tree table.

On click of child node, it should navigate to a new screen.

Looks like this:

```
>Aamir
 >Ranchi
    > 12
    > 20
 > Bangalore
    > 22
>Abhinav
 > Bangalore
   >26
```

So when user select `12`, `20` ,`22` or `26`, it should naviagte to a new screen.

Template :

```
<h3>Dynamic Columns</h3>
<p-treeTable [value]="files2" [columns]="cols" >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr [ttRow]="rowNode">
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
        <tr >
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
                <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i == 0"></p-treeTableToggler>
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>
```

Comment: could you share your template for that tree?

Comment: Thanks for response. Added the template for tree

Answer (score 1):

I think that important thing here that you didn't mention is that this is primeng-treetable.

Playing a bit with this component and reading the source code I've caught that you can use rowNode template variable that has all necessary info about the node. In your case you can check if node has no children to use link:

```
<a href="/" *ngIf="!rowNode.node.children">{{rowData.name}}</a>
<span *ngIf="rowNode.node.children">{{rowData.name}}</span>
```

You can check working stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-primeng-7cqjzl

Comment: i want to show table which consist of list of details about the children. and data vareis from children to children